# GitHub gives "This file is empty" for obviously non-empty files & folders

Tags: github, file-upload, repository

I'm trying to upload some project files into a GitHub repository. The files are a small Maven project, nothing out of the ordinary. However, when I try to upload them through GitHub's GUI, it uploads only some of the files, namely assembly.xml and pom.xml; for others, it simply displays the message "This file is empty", which makes absolutely no sense, since the folder I'm trying to upload is obviously not empty, it's "src", containing the source code and some other resources.

I'm just stumped here. What the hell? I've read through all the tutorials and they all pass this by without a second thought. This must be a bug or a quirk of some kind.

Comment: Are you actually tracking the files in those directories? Have you staged the changes to their content?

Comment: I'll have to look up what those terms mean in GitHub context. I originally supposed that there wasn't much more the the sentence "Drag files here to add them to your repository" than it seemed at the first glance.

Comment: Oh you mean on the website rather than using the desktop client?

Comment: Yes, directly on the website, in my already created repository.

Comment: Not that it explains the issue you're having, but: why don't you do it the traditional way, through the `git` CLI or a desktop client?

Comment: Someone asked me to upload my project to GItHub to collaborate on it, so I registered an account and then just went on to whatever made the most sense. And since the website gave off he impression of being able to handle what I need just fine, I never felt the need to install a client. I don't really understand GitHub that well, so I can't compare the capabilities of the website vs. the client.

Comment: DO you have any nested git repo in there? Any .git or submodules?

Comment: Nope, I simply created a new repo and tried to drag the files from my local machine into there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I also had the same issue with github .According to me you would be having an empty file in the src folder which stops the uploading of other files